# iPhone, Open custom camera, take picture, save in UITableView with GPS info

Tags: iphone, uitableview, camera, gps, image

Ok I need to open the camera, take a picture and save this in UITableView, also need to be saved the GPS info like date, place and how much km you are from the place that you take the image.
The image need to be saved in UITableView with the GPS info and every time that you take a new pic the process start again and is saving one after one in the same UITableView.

Many thanks.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want someone to do it for you? I don't think that's gonna happen. You should attempt it yourself first and then ask about stuff that you're confused about.

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to stackoverflow.

Second, this isn't really a question, so I am going to "answer" this the best way possible. It seems like you are trying to just learn how to make an iPhone application, and this is your first stab at it.

I HIGHLY recommend checking out the [stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Next, check out Apple's Sample Apps and developer library for some help in getting started:

[Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)

[Getting Started](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html)

[Photo Picker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

[Photos by Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotosByLocation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010136)

Lastly, as you are working through your code, if you stumble onto a problem, please return and as a more specific question.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

The most important GPS info for photos are:
- time
- latitude
- longitude

Slightly advanced GPS info, still important for photos:

- heading (v1)(or course) the direction in which you are going, driving; unfortunately when making a photo you have been stand still for some time, so there not always is a valid heading/course available.
- heading (v2) the direction which the camera is looking while taking that photo: if GPS is not suitable, you also can use the compass orientation.

That 3 or 4 attributes, is usually stored into jpgs using an EXIF headers. If for some reason you cannot, or don't want to store that info into the picture then you have to store that values in an own file. A simple CSV file is sufficient.